# Dll: создание необычной функции

Tags: c++, dll, функции

Как создать функцию в dll такую, что при обращении к этой функции извне часть кода функции выполняется только при первом обращении к ней, а часть - при каждом обращении к ней?

Comment: завести глобальную переменную-флажок? Но нужно подумать, а что такое "при первом обращении". Возможно, сам факт нужно будет сохранить где нибуть в файле/реесте.

Comment: Передавать в эту функцию данные... и в зависимости от этих данных `if` построить цыпочку выполнения кода

Comment: Правильно сказали, что нужно завести переменную флажок, но лучше не глобальную, а статическую (static). Смысл тот же, но видимость её будет только в теле данной функции и не будет засорять общее адресное пространство переменных.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотря что понимать под "первым выполнением".

Если в пределах одного подключения программы - достаточно `static` флага - типа

```
void firstCall()
{
    static int i = 0;
    if (i)
    {
        cout << "Next call\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "First call\n";
        ++i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    firstCall();
    firstCall();
    firstCall();
    firstCall();
    firstCall();
}
```

Если *"первое обращение"* означает что-то иное - то точно определите, что именно.

В любом случае это флаг, который до первого выполнения имеет одно значение, после - другое, и вопрос только в месте его хранения и инициализации.